# Unable to find type [UnityEngine.dll]UnityEngine.ResourceRequest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am getting this error, when I am running my game on device(Platform:Android) its in Debug log, there is no compiler error. I am not sure what is the reason of it and I couldn't find any fruitful answer over the internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and I am also getting this error with the error I have mentioned above, 05- Unable to find type [UnityEngine.dll]UnityEngine.AnimationInfo and as far as I know these are some unity resource files that are missing, FYI I am using Unity 4.6.4 f1 and my machine is Mac with OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Apart from seeing the error in the log, do you witness any incorrect application behavior?

Comment: I'm also having these errors in my logcat, along with a lot of deltatime jerkiness since 4.6.4. I'm currently using 4.6.5p1

Comment: no application is working fine, there is nothing wrong in an application.@Max Yankov